# Area plot gives strange error when plotting the same code for a 2nd time

Tags: matlab

I have a strange error: the first time I run the code listed below I get this nice plot

[image: First time plot]

[Bigger picture here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3216968/matlab%20subscript%20problem.png)

The code:

```
%% Area under the curve
subplot(1,2,1);
r = 1;
i_start = runi(r,1);
i_end = runi(r,2);
x = D(i_start:i_end,c);
y = F(i_start:i_end,c);
plot(x,y);

subplot(1,2,2);
area(x,y);
area = polyarea(x,y);
text(0.5,200, ['area:' num2str(area)])
maxD = max(D(i_start:i_end,c));
text(1.0,290, [num2str(maxD) 'mm']);
arrow([maxD/2,250],[maxD,250]);
```

When I then run the same code again without changing anything I get this error

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

When I run through the code line by line I see that the error occurs because of `area(x,y)` but I really do not understand what the problem is.

```
whos x y
Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

 x         496x1              3968  double              
 y         496x1              3968  double
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Can you either make the picture bigger, link to a full-size version, or paste your code? I don't feel like straining my eyes.

Comment: I have updatede the question now so there is a link to the big picture and the code is there.

Comment: Put `clear all` at the top of all your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've assigned the name `area` to an array, in the line

```
area = polyarea(x,y);
```

Now the line

```
area(x,y);
```

is interpreted as "get the values of the matrix `area` at the indexes given by `x` and `y`". But subscript indices have to be integers or logical values, whereas `x` and `y` are floating points.

Here are some possible solutions:

- Put the line `clear all` at the top of your script, which will clear all variable assignments (however, if you overwrite a built-in function in one line of a script and then try to call it in a later line, you will get the same issue). This also has the drawback that you lose your workspace every time you run the script, which may not be desirable.
- Rewrite your script as a function. This gives it its own local scope, so that you can't overwrite variables in the global workspace. If you need to access variables in the global workspace, you can either declare them as `global` (dangerous) or pass them in as arguments to the function (better). If you need to be able to modify arguments in the workspace, pass them back as outputs from the function and overwrite them explicitly. This is my preferred solution - in fact I never use scripts, only functions.
- Don't **ever** overwrite built-in functions! This should be a habit.

A good way to ensure that you don't override built-ins is to use a text editor that colors words according to their function. For example, this is how your code looks in my text editor ([Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)):

[image]

In line 12, it's obvious that I'm overwriting a built-in function. After a while, you learn to feel really uncomfortable when you see red text on the left of an assignment operator! If I change the name of that variable, I see this instead:

[image]

which makes me feel much happier.

Comment: I normally use color syntax heavily JAVA or other language, but MatLab has its own text editor.

Comment: Is it possible to use notepad++ and execute code snips (%%) like in the matlab text editor?